# Pandas: split a string column into component columns based on list of strings (which overlap) for starting/ending split points

Tags: python, pandas

In my Pandas string dataframe, in one column I have a big string, which I want to split apart into individual strings, each having their own row a new dataframe. The 2nd column is a label, and that same label should appear on each of the strings components.

The starting and ending split points should be determined by a set of strings. Each component string will start with encountering of one of the strings in this set. The starting point of each those strings should be in it's own column for its row, and should not be in the splitted string.

Here is an example

I have this dataframe

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 'BACKGROUND\nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious management implications and delays recruitment into clinical trials. Emerging evidence of presymptomatic disease-burden provides the rationale to develop diagnostic applications based on the evaluation of in-vivo pathological patterns early in the disease.\n\n\nOBJECTIVES\nTo outline and test a diagnostic classification approach based on an array of complementary imaging metrics in key disease-associated anatomical structures.\n\n\nMETHODS\nData from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy controls were randomly allocated in a training and validation cohort. Spatial masks were created for anatomical foci which best discriminate patients from controls in the training sample. In a virtual brain biopsy, data was then retrieved from these key disease-associated brain regions. White matter diffusivity indices, grey matter T1-signal intensity values and basal ganglia volumes were evaluated as predictor variables in a canonical discriminant function.\n\n\nRESULTS\nFollowing predictor variable selection, a classification specificity of 85.5% and sensitivity of 89.1% was achieved in the training sample and 90% specificity and 90% sensitivity in the validation sample.\n\n\nDISCUSSION\nThis study evaluates disease-associated imaging measures in a dummy diagnostic application. Although larger samples will be required for robust validation, the study confirms the potential of multimodal quantitative imaging in future clinical applications.' , 'Entry1'], 
                       [ '\nProblem statement: The industrialization of the world from whole to s ite as a result of technological innovation made many industries adopt ing Information and Communication Technology (ICT) for processing of all their activities from i nception to completion, especially in the developed nations. But, the developing nations appear to make sluggish progress towards ICT adoption due to apprehensiveness that their fraudulent activities c an easily be traced. \nApproach: The purpose of this study was to evaluate the contractor’s perception t oward ICT innovation acceptance for construction site management and the effectiveness of the innova tion. A 519 questionnaire survey was employed for the data collection, while SPSS version 17.0 wa s used for the descriptive statistic and factorial analysis of the data. \nResults: The findings show ICT innovation was effective for site management but there were positive and negative factors that affec t the ICT innovation based on the contractors view. \nConclusion: By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical eviden c has been provided for the ‘wait and see contractors’ to adopt ICT in construction site management and by making adequate provisions against the negative factors. ' , 'Entry2'], 
                       ['BACKGROUND AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associated with secondary rotator cuff muscle pathology, which is definitive for the prognosis of rotator cuff repair. There is little information regarding the early histological and immunohistochemical nature of these muscle changes in humans. We analyzed muscle biopsies from patients with supraspinatus tendon tears.\n\n\nMETHODS\nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained from 24 patients undergoing arthroscopic repair of partial- or full-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Tissue was formalin-fixed and processed for histology (for assessment of fatty infiltration and other degenerative changes) or immunohistochemistry (to identify satellite cells (CD56+), proliferating cells (Ki67+), and myofibers containing predominantly type 1 or 2 myosin heavy chain (MHC)). Myofiber diameters and the relative content of MHC1 and MHC2 were determined morphometrically.\n\n\nRESULTS\nDegenerative changes were present in both patient groups (partial and full-thickness tears). Patients with full-thickness tears had a reduced density of satellite cells, fewer proliferating cells, atrophy of MHC1+ and MHC2+ myofibers, and reduced MHC1 content.\n\n\nINTERPRETATION\nFull-thickness tears show significantly reduced muscle proliferative capacity, myofiber atrophy, and loss of MHC1 content compared to partial-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears.' ,  'Entry3']
] )
testdf.columns = ['A', 'B']
testdf.head(10)
```

This outputs

```
A   B
0   BACKGROUND\nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious management implications and delays recruitment into clinical trials. Emerging evidence of presymptomatic disease-burden provides the rationale to develop diagnostic applications based on the evaluation of in-vivo pathological patterns early in the disease.\n\n\nOBJECTIVES\nTo outline and test a diagnostic classification approach based on an array of complementary imaging metrics in key disease-associated anatomical structures.\n\n\nMETHODS\nData from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy controls were randomly allocated in a training and validation cohort. Spatial masks were created for anatomical foci which best discriminate patients from controls in the training sample. In a virtual brain biopsy, data was then retrieved from these key disease-associated brain regions. White matter diffusivity indices, grey matter T1-signal intensity values and basal ganglia volumes were evaluated as predictor variables in a canonical discriminant function.\n\n\nRESULTS\nFollowing predictor variable selection, a classification specificity of 85.5% and sensitivity of 89.1% was achieved in the training sample and 90% specificity and 90% sensitivity in the validation sample.\n\n\nDISCUSSION\nThis study evaluates disease-associated imaging measures in a dummy diagnostic application. Although larger samples will be required for robust validation, the study confirms the potential of multimodal quantitative imaging in future clinical applications. Entry1
1   \nProblem statement: The industrialization of the world from whole to s ite as a result of technological innovation made many industries adopt ing Information and Communication Technology (ICT) for processing of all their activities from i nception to completion, especially in the developed nations. But, the developing nations appear to make sluggish progress towards ICT adoption due to apprehensiveness that their fraudulent activities c an easily be traced. \nApproach: The purpose of this study was to evaluate the contractor’s perception t oward ICT innovation acceptance for construction site management and the effectiveness of the innova tion. A 519 questionnaire survey was employed for the data collection, while SPSS version 17.0 wa s used for the descriptive statistic and factorial analysis of the data. \nResults: The findings show ICT innovation was effective for site management but there were positive and negative factors that affec t the ICT innovation based on the contractors view. \nConclusion: By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical eviden c has been provided for the ‘wait and see contractors’ to adopt ICT in construction site management and by making adequate provisions against the negative factors.\t Entry2
2   BACKGROUND AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associated with secondary rotator cuff muscle pathology, which is definitive for the prognosis of rotator cuff repair. There is little information regarding the early histological and immunohistochemical nature of these muscle changes in humans. We analyzed muscle biopsies from patients with supraspinatus tendon tears.\n\n\nMETHODS\nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained from 24 patients undergoing arthroscopic repair of partial- or full-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Tissue was formalin-fixed and processed for histology (for assessment of fatty infiltration and other degenerative changes) or immunohistochemistry (to identify satellite cells (CD56+), proliferating cells (Ki67+), and myofibers containing predominantly type 1 or 2 myosin heavy chain (MHC)). Myofiber diameters and the relative content of MHC1 and MHC2 were determined morphometrically.\n\n\nRESULTS\nDegenerative changes were present in both patient groups (partial and full-thickness tears). Patients with full-thickness tears had a reduced density of satellite cells, fewer proliferating cells, atrophy of MHC1+ and MHC2+ myofibers, and reduced MHC1 content.\n\n\nINTERPRETATION\nFull-thickness tears show significantly reduced muscle proliferative capacity, myofiber atrophy, and loss of MHC1 content compared to partial-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Entry3
```

And I have a set of these strings

```
listStrings = { 
'\nIntroduction' , '\nCase' , 
'\nLiterature' , '\nBackground',  '\nRelated' , 
'\nMethods' , '\nMethod',
'\nTechniques', '\nMethodology',
'\nResults', '\nResult', '\nExperimental',
'\nExperiments', '\nExperiment',
'\nDiscussion' , '\nLimitations',
'\nConclusion' , '\nConclusions',
'\nConcluding' ,
'Introduction\n' , 'Case\n' , 
'Literature\n' , 'Background\n',  'Related\n' , 
'Methods\n' , 'Method\n',
'Techniques\n', 'Methodology\n',
'Results\n', 'Result\n', 'Experimental\n',
'Experiments\n', 'Experiment\n',
'Discussion\n' , 'Limitations\n',
'Conclusion\n' , 'Conclusions\n',
'Concluding\n' ,
'INTRODUCTION' , 'CASE' , 
'LITERATURE' , 'BACKGROUND',  'RELATED' , 
'METHODS' , 'METHOD',
'TECHNIQUES', 'METHODOLOGY',
'RESULTS', 'RESULT', 'EXPERIMENTAL',
'EXPERIMENTS', 'EXPERIMENT',
'DISCUSSION' , 'LIMITATIONS',
'CONCLUSION' , 'CONCLUSIONS',
'CONCLUDING' ,
'Introduction:' , 'Case:' , 
'Literature:' , 'Background:',  'Related:' , 
'Methods:' , 'Method:',
'Techniques:', 'Methodology:',
'Results:', 'Result:', 'Experimental:',
'Experiments:', 'Experiment:',
'Discussion:' , 'Limitations:',
'Conclusion:' , 'Conclusions:',
'Concluding:' ,
}
```

Until a string in Column A reaches one of the strings in `listStrings`, do not save anything. Once it reaches one of the strings in `listStrings`, put that `listStrings` string as it's own separate column in a row of a new dataframe. Then put everything after That `listStrings` string in a new row until that segment reaches another string from `listStrings`. Then reapeat the process: place that string in a new column, and create a new row for the new segment, and so on.

Here is an example of what the ideal result should be

```
testdf2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 'BACKGROUND' , '\nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious management implications and delays recruitment into clinical trials. Emerging evidence of presymptomatic disease-burden provides the rationale to develop diagnostic applications based on the evaluation of in-vivo pathological patterns early in the disease.\n\nOBJECTIVES\nTo outline and test a diagnostic classification approach based on an array of complementary imaging metrics in key disease-associated anatomical structures.\n\n', 'Entry1'],
    ['METHODS', 'Data from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy controls were randomly allocated in a training and validation cohort. Spatial masks were created for anatomical foci which best discriminate patients from controls in the training sample. In a virtual brain biopsy, data was then retrieved from these key disease-associated brain regions. White matter diffusivity indices, grey matter T1-signal intensity values and basal ganglia volumes were evaluated as predictor variables in a canonical discriminant function.\n\n', 'Entry1'],
    ['RESULTS', '\nFollowing predictor variable selection, a classification specificity of 85.5% and sensitivity of 89.1% was achieved in the training sample and 90% specificity and 90% sensitivity in the validation sample.\n\n', 'Entry1'],
    ['DISCUSSION', '\nThis study evaluates disease-associated imaging measures in a dummy diagnostic application. Although larger samples will be required for robust validation, the study confirms the potential of multimodal quantitative imaging in future clinical applications.' , 'Entry1'], 
                        ['\nResults:', ' The findings show ICT innovation was effective for site management but there were positive and negative factors that affec t the ICT innovation based on the contractors view. ', 'Entry2'],
                         ['\nConclusion:',' By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical eviden c has been provided for the wait and see contractors to adopt ICT in construction site management and by making adequate provisions against the negative factors.', 'Entry2'], 
                       ['BACKGROUND',  'AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associated with secondary rotator cuff muscle pathology, which is definitive for the prognosis of rotator cuff repair. There is little information regarding the early histological and immunohistochemical nature of these muscle changes in humans. We analyzed muscle biopsies from patients with supraspinatus tendon tears.\n\n', 'Entry3'],
                      [ 'METHODS', '\nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained from 24 patients undergoing arthroscopic repair of partial- or full-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Tissue was formalin-fixed and processed for histology (for assessment of fatty infiltration and other degenerative changes) or immunohistochemistry (to identify satellite cells (CD56+), proliferating cells (Ki67+), and myofibers containing predominantly type 1 or 2 myosin heavy chain (MHC)). Myofiber diameters and the relative content of MHC1 and MHC2 were determined morphometrically.\n\n',  'Entry3'],
                      [ 'RESULTS', '\nDegenerative changes were present in both patient groups (partial and full-thickness tears). Patients with full-thickness tears had a reduced density of satellite cells, fewer proliferating cells, atrophy of MHC1+ and MHC2+ myofibers, and reduced MHC1 content.\n\n\nINTERPRETATION\nFull-thickness tears show significantly reduced muscle proliferative capacity, myofiber atrophy, and loss of MHC1 content compared to partial-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears.', 'Entry3']
])
testdf2.columns = ['C' , 'D', 'E']
testdf2.head(20)
```

Which will  result in

```
C   D   E
0   BACKGROUND  \nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious management implications and delays recruitment into clinical trials. Emerging evidence of presymptomatic disease-burden provides the rationale to develop diagnostic applications based on the evaluation of in-vivo pathological patterns early in the disease.\n\nOBJECTIVES\nTo outline and test a diagnostic classification approach based on an array of complementary imaging metrics in key disease-associated anatomical structures.\n\n    Entry1
1   METHODS Data from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy controls were randomly allocated in a training and validation cohort. Spatial masks were created for anatomical foci which best discriminate patients from controls in the training sample. In a virtual brain biopsy, data was then retrieved from these key disease-associated brain regions. White matter diffusivity indices, grey matter T1-signal intensity values and basal ganglia volumes were evaluated as predictor variables in a canonical discriminant function.\n\n Entry1
2   RESULTS \nFollowing predictor variable selection, a classification specificity of 85.5% and sensitivity of 89.1% was achieved in the training sample and 90% specificity and 90% sensitivity in the validation sample.\n\n  Entry1
3   DISCUSSION  \nThis study evaluates disease-associated imaging measures in a dummy diagnostic application. Although larger samples will be required for robust validation, the study confirms the potential of multimodal quantitative imaging in future clinical applications.  Entry1
4   \nResults:  The findings show ICT innovation was effective for site management but there were positive and negative factors that affec t the ICT innovation based on the contractors view.  Entry2
5   \nConclusion:   By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical eviden c has been provided for the wait and see contractors to adopt ICT in construction site management and by making adequate provisions against the negative factors.    Entry2
6   BACKGROUND  AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associated with secondary rotator cuff muscle pathology, which is definitive for the prognosis of rotator cuff repair. There is little information regarding the early histological and immunohistochemical nature of these muscle changes in humans. We analyzed muscle biopsies from patients with supraspinatus tendon tears.\n\n    Entry3
7   METHODS \nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained from 24 patients undergoing arthroscopic repair of partial- or full-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Tissue was formalin-fixed and processed for histology (for assessment of fatty infiltration and other degenerative changes) or immunohistochemistry (to identify satellite cells (CD56+), proliferating cells (Ki67+), and myofibers containing predominantly type 1 or 2 myosin heavy chain (MHC)). Myofiber diameters and the relative content of MHC1 and MHC2 were determined morphometrically.\n\n Entry3
8   RESULTS \nDegenerative changes were present in both patient groups (partial and full-thickness tears). Patients with full-thickness tears had a reduced density of satellite cells, fewer proliferating cells, atrophy of MHC1+ and MHC2+ myofibers, and reduced MHC1 content.\n\n\nINTERPRETATION\nFull-thickness tears show significantly reduced muscle proliferative capacity, myofiber atrophy, and loss of MHC1 content compared to partial-thickness supraspinatus tendon tears. Entry3
```

The original labels column B that corresponded to each of the original strings in the first dataframe are given to each row for the string segments of the new dataframe.

The strings in `listStrings` are excluded in the segment, and are instead extracted into it's own column.

Finally, there may be overlap in the strings in `listStrings`. It does not matter which side the overlap first occurs, or which one is selected for the column, or if a combination (ie '\nResult;') is used. As seen in row 4 and 5 in the second example dataframe.

Edit:

For a solution I need column B to be transferred over to Column E in the sample solution given above, each of the entries in Column B is an important label, and I would need each component string in Column E to contain it's original label.

Comment: Do you want the column `E`?

Comment: yes, I want to keep track of all the component strings which belong to the same original string

Comment: To be more specific, Column E comes from Column B, which is an important label for each of the chunks of text for the application I am working on, so for this minimal-ish example, I would like the solution to be the same and include the values of Column E in the example solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach, which I'm not certain of efficiency for big dataset:

```
# first we build a big regex pattern
pat = '|'.join(listStrings)

# find all keywords in the series
new_df = testdf.A.str.findall(pat)
# 0    [BACKGROUND, METHODS, RESULT, DISCUSSION]
# 1                    [\nResults, \nConclusion]
# 2                [BACKGROUND, METHODS, RESULT]
# Name: A, dtype: object

# find all the chunks by splitting the text with the found keywords
chunks = pd.concat([testdf.A.iloc[[i]].str.split('|'.join(new_df.iloc[i]), expand=True) 
             for i in range(len(testdf))]).stack()

# stack the keywords:
keys = new_df.str.join(' ').str.split(' ', expand=True).stack()

# out return dataframe
# note that we shift the chunks to match the keywords
pd.DataFrame({'D': keys, 'E': chunks.groupby(level=0).shift(-1)})
```

Output:

```
                D                                                  E
0 0    BACKGROUND  \nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious ma...
  1       METHODS  \nData from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy con...
  2        RESULT  S\nFollowing predictor variable selection, a c...
  3    DISCUSSION  \nThis study evaluates disease-associated imag...
  4           NaN                                                NaN
1 0     \nResults  : The findings show ICT innovation was effecti...
  1  \nConclusion  : By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical ...
  2           NaN                                                NaN
2 0    BACKGROUND   AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associate...
  1       METHODS  \nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained ...
  2        RESULT  S\nDegenerative changes were present in both p...
  3           NaN                                                NaN
```

Edit:

Here is a version of the solution that gives the exact output specified in the question

```
# first we build a big regex pattern
pat = '|'.join(listStrings)

# find all keywords in the series
new_df = testdf.A.str.findall(pat)
# 0    [BACKGROUND, METHODS, RESULT, DISCUSSION]
# 1                    [\nResults, \nConclusion]
# 2                [BACKGROUND, METHODS, RESULT]
# Name: A, dtype: object

# find all the chunks by splitting the text with the found keywords
chunks = pd.concat([testdf.A.iloc[[i]].str.split('|'.join(new_df.iloc[i]), expand=True) 
             for i in range(len(testdf))]).stack()

# stack the keywords:
keys = np.concatenate(new_df.values) # Flatten the keywords array
values = chunks.groupby(level=0).shift(-1).dropna().values
labels = np.concatenate([len(val) * [testdf['B'][ind]] for ind, val in enumerate(new_df.values)]) 
# out return dataframe
# note that we shift the chunks to match the keywords
pd.DataFrame({'C': keys, 'D': values, 'E': labels})
```

Output:

```
C   D   E
0   BACKGROUND  \nDiagnostic uncertainty in ALS has serious ma...   Entry1
1   METHODS \nData from 75 ALS patients and 75 healthy con...   Entry1
2   RESULTS \nFollowing predictor variable selection, a cl...   Entry1
3   DISCUSSION  \nThis study evaluates disease-associated imag...   Entry1
4   \nResult    s: The findings show ICT innovation was effect...   Entry2
5   \nConclusion    : By evaluating the ICT innovation, empirical ...   Entry2
6   BACKGROUND  AND PURPOSE\nRotator cuff tears are associate...    Entry3
7   METHODS \nSupraspinatus muscle biopsies were obtained ...   Entry3
8   RESULTS \nDegenerative changes were present in both pa...   Entry3
```

Comment: I am curious what the line `for i in range(len(testdf))]).stack()` is doing? It's a loop, but there's nothing inside the loop

Comment: it goes through the `testdf` again (`testdf.A.iloc[[i]]`) and breaks the text in each line into chunks, given the keywords found.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite solve the solution, since I needed the third column in the sample solution to keep track of which original string each chunk belonged to . 'Entry1', 'Entry2', 'Entry3', etc.

Comment: In the output data frame, the first level index is the (index of the) original string, the second index is the order of the keyword/chunk in each string. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, I am looking at the dataframe, but it looks like the 'keys' and 'chuck' keep track how each chunk belonged to the original string. I am wondering if we could somehow switch that integer keys with the original entry of column B in the original dataframe

Comment: Yes, that's what I specified so I'll mark it as solved, and make a new question for trying to also include the original column. I'll still need the label of the original column B, and I had no idea you can do keys in Pandas so wasn't expecting for you to come up with the solution that you did xD

Comment: Actually I don't think I'm allowed to make a new question because it'll be exactly the same as the old one, since I put an example of what I am looking for. I'll be more specific of why I need column B

Comment: I edited your answer to match the specified output in the prompt.

Comment: Approved. Apparently I've been misunderstanding your output all the way. Glad it helps.